# call function for each row

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I use Access. I have stored function what return random keywords from another table. If I insert this function in my SQL query receive on each line the same result (same keywords).
How to easy achieve in SQL call this function for every line?

```
SELECT ID, StoredFunction() AS Result
FROM Table
```

_

```
 ID     Result
-------------------
 1  | 1 result 
 2  | 1 result
 3  | 1 result
```

I need

```
  ID    Result
-------------------
 1  | 1 result 
 2  | 2 result
 3  | 3 result
```

Comment: OK, what's the question here?

Comment: There are a few keys bits of information missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you are getting the same result in each row is due to Access trying to optimize the query for you. It sees `StoredFunction()` called once for each row and believes that **since there is no argument passed in to the function**, all calls should return the same result. That's clearly incorrect about the nature of your function. You can avoid this automatic optimization by passing one or more arguments into the function. The arguments don't have to be used in any way, but Access will see `StoredFunction(ID)` as something that it needs to call on every row because the results may be different. All you need to do is change the declaration of your function from `Public StoredFunction() As Variant` to `Public StoredFunction(v As Variant) As Variant`. Then, change your query to `SELECT ID, StoredFunction(ID) AS Result FROM Table`. You don't need to change anything *inside the function itself*.

Comment: Logical and simple. Thanks a lot :-)